# Asymmetry in Linux VM transfer rate

Tags: linux, linux-networking, iperf

I have two Linux VMs, let's call them VM1 and VM2.
I have on VM1 an 80 Gb file.
When I try to transfer this file from VM1 to VM2 the transfer rate is almost 256 Mb/s.

```
scp 80Gblargefile VM2:/home/myuser
```

Then I remove the file from VM1 and, always in VM1, I try to copy back it from VM2:

```
scp VM2:/home/myuser/80Gblargefile .
```

In this case, the transfer rate is 46 Mb/s.

The transfer always occurs on the same network interface.

I would like to understand if it is normally a situation like this. If no, what I can do to debug the problem? I suspect there is a problem with a kernel parameter or network configuration. But I don't know what to check.

I verified with traceroute there is one hop between the two VMs. Moreover, I tested the bandwidth with iperf From VM2 (as a server) and VM1 and I got:

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  14.8 GBytes  12.7 Gbits/sec
```

I did also the reverse:

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  14.7 GBytes  12.6 Gbits/sec
```

Comment: Do those machines have the same parameters like CPU, memory, and expected network bandwidth? Do you run them in cloud or in a private datacenter?

Comment: They are in IBM Cloud, they have same CPU, memory, network bandwidth as you can see from iperf outputs.